# Is it possible to get a click event from the chrome external protocol request?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, launching-application, protocol-handler

[image]

Is there any chance to track the click event on this div/pop up?Like if a user clicked on "Launch Application" button or "Do Nothing" button?

Also,is it possible to know whether the div has actually appeared in the first place? ( I know we can track through on blur event but it isn't accurate)

Comment: Why do you need to listen to the click event? What is your goal?

Comment: @boopathy Did you  find the answer for this?