# Is there any event or notification for the background page when a user chooses not to open an app with the default protocol handler?

Tags: javascript, dom

For a possibly familiar example, when you click a zoom link and chrome provides an "Open Zoom?" ok/cancel dialog, does the "Launching..." page in the background get any event or notification of the user's choice?

I am working on a similar page and would like to provide a different message, close the tab, or some other behavior depending on the user's choice to cancel vs open, is this information available to my "launching" page?

[image]

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/836777/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/24571548/1048572

Comment: @ShivashriganeshMahato That's absolutely unrelated

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29343704/is-it-possible-to-get-a-click-event-from-the-chrome-external-protocol-request? Unfortunately that's not been answered in five years…